# req missing cookie from android

Tags: android, express, ab-testing

I'm using express-ab to integrate ab testing. When testing with POSTMAN, I see that the ab test is saved into req.cookies.ab, but when I test with android, req.cookies.ab is undefined.

I'm doing something like this on the express server:

```
//TESTS
var tests = [
      "default-test-1"
    , "default-test-2"
];

abtests.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    next();
    req.tests = [];
});

tests.forEach(function (test) {
    abtests.get("/", ab.test(test, .5), function (req, res, next) {
        next();
    });
});

abtests.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(req.cookies.ab));
});
```

Can someone shed some light on the subject? Thanks!